# How to select data from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a database with a structure, roughly like

```
// An index to track Ada's memberships
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      // Index Ada's groups in her profile
      "groups": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         "techpioneers": true,
         "womentechmakers": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "groups": {
    "techpioneers": {
      "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to select users who are members of the same set of groups

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to define an additional `group_combinations` or `all_groups` index, where you store each user under their combines the groups:

```
all_groups: {
  "techpioneers_womentechmakers": {
    alovelace: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the simplest version, also thinking about it, I can not think of anything better. I'll try to make the groups combinations automatically change through cloud functions

Comment: Yeah, this is indeed one of those things that I'd also prefer to do server-side. Also make sure to sort the category names alphabetically, so that you have a consistent result even when they arrive in a different order.